# How to reference a parent resource name to a resource inside a module using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

How to reference a parent resource name to a  resource inside a module using Microsoft bicep code.

Below main.bicep file code is working.

```
# main.bicep

param apimName string = 'devApim'
param apimLocation string = 'eastus'
param publisherName string = 'danny'
param publisherEmail string = 'danny@gmail.com'

param api_display_name string = 'Test Consumer API'
param api_description         = 'Test API description'
param api_versioningScheme    = 'Segment'

resource devApim_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  name: apimName
  location: apimLocation
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
}


resource test_api_vs_v1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apiVersionSets@2021-01-01-preview' = {
// Below reference to first/parent resource is working fine as it's in the same bicep file.
  parent: devApim_resource
  name: 'test_api_vs_name'
  properties: {
    displayName: api_display_name
    description: api_description
    versioningScheme: api_versioningScheme
  }
}
```

I want to modify this main.bicep second resource(VersionSet resource) into a module like the below files.

```
# main.bicep

param apimName string = 'devApim'
param apimLocation string = 'eastus'
param publisherName string = 'danny'
param publisherEmail string = 'danny@gmail.com'

param api_display_name string = 'Test Consumer API'
param api_description         = 'Test API description'
param api_versioningScheme    = 'Segment'


resource devApim_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  name: apimName
  location: apimLocation
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
}

module test_api_module 'test-api.bicep' = {
  name: 'test_api'
  params: {
    api_display_name: api_display_name
    api_description: api_description
    api_versioningScheme: api_versioningScheme
     
  }
  
}
```

```
# test-api.bicep file

param api_display_name string 
param api_description  string
param api_versioningScheme string 

resource test_api_vs_v1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apiVersionSets@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  // Below reference to first/parent resource is not working.
  //parent: devApim_resource 

  name: 'test_api_vs_name'
  properties: {
    displayName: api_display_name
    description: api_description
    versioningScheme: api_versioningScheme
  }
}
```

Now how do I reference/pass parent resource 'devApim_resource' (first resource) into module resource test_api_vs_v1 (second resource) as using parent: devApim_resource is not working in test-api.bicep module file

I'm very new to bicep coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found this documentation for more detail:

- [Reference existing resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/resource-declaration?tabs=azure-powershell#reference-existing-resources)

You need to add the parent resource name as a parameter in your child module:

```bicep
param apimName string
```

Then you can reference an existing resource like this:

```bicep
// Reference to the parent resource
resource devApim_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' existing = {
  name: apimName
}

resource test_api_vs_v1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apiVersionSets@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: devApim_resource 
  name: 'test_api_vs_name'
  ...
}
```

Then in your `main.bicep`, you can call you the chil module like that:

```bicep
module test_api_module 'test-api.bicep' = {
  name: 'test_api'
  params: {
    apimName: devApim_resource.name
    api_display_name: api_display_name
    api_description: api_description
    api_versioningScheme: api_versioningScheme     
  }  
}
```

Comment: resource devApim_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' existing = {
  name: apimName
}

Comment: Does the Above comment syntax also help in getting a resource definition in bicep just like terraform import or it's just used for referencing between needed resources?

Comment: Using the `existing` keyword also allow you to retrieve the resource properties

Comment: Ok, thanks @Thomas. Say I have a storage account in azure with the name 'examplestorage456'.  How do I retrieve this resource properties using the below bicep code? Like just by running this command or some other way.                                          "  az deployment group create -g test12 -f storage-account.bicep  -c  "

Comment: resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' existing = { name: 'examplestorage456' }

Comment: you could use output: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell.

Comment: But it seems using `existing` only works if your parent resource has been deployed completely otherwise you will get not found error.

How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/child-resource-name-type#full-resource-name-outside-parent) states, you do not need to reference the parent resource if your child resource name contains your parent resource name before slash. So you only have to pass the parent resource name into the module and insert it into the child's resource name.

```
# main.bicep

param apimName string = 'devApim'
...


resource devApim_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  name: apimName
  ...
}

module test_api_module 'test-api.bicep' = {
  name: 'test_api'
  params: {
    apimName: devApim_resource.name
    ...
  }
}
```

---

```
# test-api.bicep file

param apimName string 
... 

resource test_api_vs_v1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apiVersionSets@2021-01-01-preview' = {  
  name: '${apimName}/test_api_vs_name'
  properties: {
    ...
  }
}
```

This will create `test_api_vs_name` version set as a child of `test_api` APIM instance.